Upgrading libpython3-stdlib causes removal of most basic packages in Ubuntu 22.04
For some time I've been having the following message when running apt upgrade: The following packages have been kept back: libpython3-stdlib python3 python3-apt python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources. Upon trying to run: sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade... I get messages about holding broken packages and unmet dependencies due to packages versions conflicts. Example:
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib python3 python3-apt python3-dev python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.10.6-1~22.04.1) but 3.12.5-1 is to be installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.12~) but 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libapt-pkg6.0t64 (>= 2.7.11) but it is not installable
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 13.1) but 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
 python3-jsonschema : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not installable
 python3-minimal : PreDepends: python3.12-minimal (>= 3.12.4-1~) but it is not installable
 python3-pbr : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not installable
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not installable

So I started to consider just removing or reinstalling the python3 with its dependencies, but I immediately saw that it would practically break the entire system by removing many of basic packages like apt, gnome, linux-tools, ubuntu-desktop and many others. So I just tried to manually install libpython3-stdlib and it gave the same thing:
sudo apt install libpython3-stdlib
...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3-stdlib
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 239 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Does anyone know why this happens and maybe have any suggestions on how could I effectively purge and reinstall python3 without removing non-python packages and breaking the entire system?

Ubuntu 20.04 should be using Python3.8. The packages in your output seem clearly labelled 22.04, and wrong-release package are a common cause exactly this kind of error. Return to Python3.8, uninstall all the higher versions, and disable whatever PPA or wrong-version source you got all those wrong version packages from. That should solve the error.

If you really want to use Python 3.10 (or higher), you can. But you must to install them in a different way after you have fixed the current mess. There are several safe ways. Tarball. Conda. Venv. Container. Many options.

You ask why this has happened:  This has happened because a user with sudo privileges added inappropriate sources to your system, polluting a focal or 20.04 system with packages intended for later releases of Ubuntu.

My bad, I've mistyped. My Ubuntu version is actually 22.04.5. Afaik, python 3.10 is the default version for that distro.
